# Конфликт Imgui и SOIL C++ OpenGL GLFW

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, imgui

Решил создать игру со своими правилами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключил Imgui, точнее раскомментировал подключение так как еще в начале вылезла ошибка.
Если я использую отдельно soil все норм. Imgui так же отдельно работает. но вместе выдает ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
1>SOIL.lib(SOIL.obj) : warning LNK4075: не учитывается "/EDITANDCONTINUE" из-за спецификации "/OPT:ICF"
```

1>MSVCRT.lib(initializers.obj) : warning LNK4098: библиотека по умолчанию "msvcrtd.lib" противоречит использованию других библиотек; используйте параметр /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>msvcrtd.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__CrtDbgReport"
1>msvcrtd.lib(init.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__CrtDbgReportW"
1>D:\Розробка 2.0\С++\craft c++\NewCraft\Release\NewCraft.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 2
1>Сборка проекта "NewCraft.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.

Внесение в С++ командную строку /NODEFAULTLIB:library не влияет ни на что
Пробовал использовать freimage, модифицировал текстур лоадер под freimage работает, но я не умею загружать прозрачные текстуры при помощи freimage  да и еще там тип нужно указывать, ужас по этому хочу остаться на soil, но суть, заработало как поправить чтобы работало с soil.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Функция загрузки текстур

```
    GLuint loadTexture(char const * path, GLint paramMin, GLint paramMax)
{
    GLuint textureID = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    int width, height, nrComponents;



    unsigned char *data = SOIL_load_image(path, &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        GLenum format;
        if (nrComponents == 1)
            format = GL_RED;
        else if (nrComponents == 3)
            format = GL_RGB;
        else if (nrComponents == 4)
            format = GL_RGBA;

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


        
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);


        //   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
          // glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, paramMin);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, paramMax);


        SOIL_free_image_data(data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Texture failed to load at path: " << path << std::endl;
        SOIL_free_image_data(data);
    }
    
    return textureID;
}


GLuint loadTexture(char const * path)
{

    return loadTexture(path, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR);
}
```

Comment: Хорошо исправляю

Comment: Видимо были использованы разные настройки для сборки разных частей программы, прежде всего то, что на странице Code Generation, или даже сборка разными тулсетами.

Comment: Чесно говоря не понимаю про что вы.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду что либ файл soil не правильно скомпилирован?

Comment: Не то чтобы неправильно, скорее не так, так остальные. Отсюда и конфликты линковки. Следует следить, чтобы все единицы трансляции собирались со строго одинаковыми, или хотя бы со совместимыми, настройками.

Comment: Просто обычно настройки от автора не меняю, но попробую позже перекомпелировать.

Comment: Пересобрал, но не помогло

Comment: Действительно помогло, soil был собран как Debug, Пересобрал как realase. Пасиб.

Comment: https://question-it.com/questions/3202161/nerazreshennyj-vneshnij-simvol-corba-server Стаття где описано, находил ее но без вашего  комента не обращал внимания и даже не думал что такое возможно.